# How do I remove road and country labels in MKLookAroundView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

I want to remove the street names etc in LookAround in my SwiftUI app. I can’t seem to find any working solutions to this. I’ve seen other apps pull this off and I just can’t find the solution. Please help me

[image: Here is what I want to remove]

I tried something like this, but it isn't working.

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MKLookAroundViewController {
        let lookAroundViewController = MKLookAroundViewController()
        lookAroundViewController.isNavigationEnabled = true // Enable navigation controls
        lookAroundViewController.showsRoadLabels = false // Hide road labels (not working)
        lookAroundViewController.pointOfInterestFilter = .excludingAll // Exclude points of interest
        lookAroundViewController.badgePosition = .bottomTrailing // Set badge position
        
        // Assign initial scene if available
        if let initialScene = initialScene {
            lookAroundViewController.scene = initialScene
        }
        
        return lookAroundViewController
    }
```